Summation theorem for primary (Seidel) aberrations
I am trying to derive the summation theorem for primary aberrations, following Welford's classic book on optical aberration theory (readable at https://www.scribd.com/document/593269643/W-T-Welford). However, I am unable to get the result as stated in the book.
PRELUDE:
In Chapter 8, he calculates the wavefront aberration using the formula (8.1):

However, the corresponding figure does not include the primed points $A', \bar{A'}, P'$, or mention which region has refractive index $n/n'$. Does anyone have any idea where this formula comes from?

QUESTION:
Here is my attempt at proving the formula, which seems to show that the formula is slightly incorrect. Consider the following image:

Here, $Q$ and $\bar{P}$ are the points where the two rays intersect the refracting surface. $A'$ and $\bar{A}'$ lie on a reference sphere centered at O, before the refracting surface, while $A$ and $\bar{A}$ lie on a reference sphere after refraction. Also ,$B'$ and $\bar{B}'$ lie on the wavefront before refraction, while $B$ and $\bar{B}$ lie on the wavefront after refraction. The refractive indices of the object and image space are $n'$ and $n$ respectively.
The total wavefront aberration of the ray $O'Q$ is given by:
$$W = nBA = nQA- nQB$$
Now, since the wavefronts are smoothly varying, we can choose the before/after wavefronts such that $nQB = n'QB'$, and therefore:
$$W = nQA - n'QB'$$
To isolate the aberration contributed by the refracting surface in question, we subtract the aberration before refraction:
$$\Delta W = W - n'B'A' = (nQA - n'QB') - n'B'A'$$
$$\Delta W = nQA - n'QA'$$
Now, if we do the same for the ray $O'\bar{P}$, we might incorrectly conclude that the total aberration of ray $O'Q$ wrt the ray $O'\bar{P}$ can be expressed as surface-by-surface summation as
$$W = \sum n'(\bar{P}\bar{A}'-QA') - n(\bar{P}\bar{A}-QA)$$
However, this is incorrect, as the condition $n\bar{P}\bar{B} = n'\bar{P}\bar{B}'$ is only valid if $\bar{P}$ and $Q$ both lie on the same wavefront, which is not generally true. Thus, it seems that the formula $8.1$ in the aforementioned text is incorrect.

likely, the source is in "$n$" and the image is in "$n'$"

@hyportnex I have added the figure from the book, and I am not so sure.

I am not so sure either but check out Section 7.5, and especially Fig 7.5 on page 102

@hyportnex The closest I can get (see update) is by assuming $n$ is the image space refractive index.
